# How set a file size limit in asp with RadUpload telerik IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net, file, file-upload, telerik, radupload

I am having issues regarding this Radupload control with the Telerik library.
 I can only upload files to my server less than 5 Mb ...
 Why?
 Yet I have followed the tutorials and configured the web.config file with access rights to files.

Here is my code config

**RadUpload :**

```
<telerik:RadUpload ID="radUpload_FileShare" runat="server" style="margin-left:140px;margin-top:20px;" 
InitialFileInputsCount="1"
MaxFileSize="318000000"
MaxFileInputsCount="14"
OnClientFileSelected="DeleteInvalidInputs_File"
controlobjectsvisibility="Default" 
></telerik:RadUpload>
```

**Web.config :**

```
<system.web>
      <httpRuntime
     executionTimeout="1000000" maxRequestLength="500000" />
</system.web>
```

And i have add acces in my folder with "NETWORKSERVICE"

Thank's a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer here since this is an older question, but IIS 7 has a different place to set the max file upload size.  See this link for more information:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/09/24/from-iis6-maxrequestlength-to-iis7-maxallowedcontentlengthfile-specifying-maximum-file-upload-size.aspx

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="500000" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Ohhhh Yess ! Thank's  a looot ^^